# authenticate user to mongo db on docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I am trying to use docker in my existing project. I have two extra services, redis and mongodb. I am having issue on creating user and authenticating that user to able to use database. I don't want to do by running the container(docker exec -it ...) and creating the user and grant the permission over there. This way every developer has to do it on their machine. Instead, I want to have script which runs when creating a mongodb image.

Here is how I am trying

```
const {
  DATABASE_HOST,
  DATABASE_PORT,
  DATABASE_DBNAME,
  DATABASE_DBUSER,
  DATABASE_DBPASS,
} = require('../configs');

console.log('DATABASE', DATABASE_HOST);

db.createUser({
  user: DATABASE_DBUSER,
  pwd: DATABASE_DBPASS,
  roles: [
    {
      role: 'readWrite',
      db: DATABASE_DBNAME,
    },
  ],
});
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

# Lets define all our services (i.e. our containers to run)
services:
    # create a mongodb database
    travel-db:
        image: mongo
        container_name: "travel-db"
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        volumes:
            - ./src/helpers/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
            - "mongodb:/data/db/"
        # opening mongodb port so that it can be connected from host
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
    # create redis-server
    travel-redis-server:
        image: redis:latest
        container_name: "travel-redis-server"
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        volumes:
            - redis:/data/
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"

    # express app
    travel-express-server:
        image: "travel-express-server"
        container_name: "travel-express-server"
        env_file:
            - ./.env
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"

volumes:
    mongodb: {}
    redis: {}
```

I am getting following error

[image]

UPDATE

i changed mongo-init.js to

```
db.createUser({
  user: 'traveluser',
  pwd: 'travel123',
  roles: [
    {
      role: 'readWrite',
      db: 'travel_db',
    },
  ],
});
```

it then says the following

```
Successfully added user: {
travel-db                |   "user" : "traveluser",
travel-db                |   "roles" : [
travel-db                |           {
travel-db                |                   "role" : "readWrite",
travel-db                |                   "db" : "travel_db"
travel-db                |           }
travel-db                |   ]
travel-db                | }
```

but still getting error on authentication

`SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for traveluser on travel_db from client 172.20.0.4:36562 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user "traveluser" for db "travel_db"`

if i use

```
environment:
   - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
   - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
```

and then comment the following `- ./src/helpers/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro` and change env variable with admin access then it works but not other than admin.

Comment: you didn't specify which database to create the user in, so it was probably created in the admin database.  Try using `admin` as the authentication database.

Comment: do you mean to say to include `use admin` when creating user?

Comment: That's the default. I mean when you are trying to connect add `authSource=admin` to your connection string, or use the `--authenticationDatabase admin` option, or whichever function is appropriate for the driver you are using.

Comment: to confirm, do you mean to say on this let dbUrl = `mongodb://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_DBNAME}?authSource=${DATABASE_DBNAME}`; ?

Comment: it works for admin case but not for other user.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you use `mongodb://${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}/${DATABASE_DBNAME}?authSource=admin`

Comment: that way i get the same error, User not found could not '' find this for db ''

Comment: if the authSource applied properly, the error should mention the admin db not the db you intend to query.

Comment: sorry i used authSource on different place. Now i am getting UserNotFound: Could not find user "traveluser" for db "admin"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213231/discussion-between-serenity-and-joe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` is not a function in the mongo shell.  If you need to read javascript code from a file, use the `load` function.

The user is likely being created in the wrong database.  You can explicitly specify which database when creating:

```
db.getSiblingDB("travel_db").createUser({
  user: 'traveluser',
  pwd: 'travel123',
  roles: [
    {
      role: 'readWrite',
      db: 'travel_db',
    },
  ],
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. can you show it an example, please?

Comment: removing the require and hardcoding the values for db setup did not work either.

Comment: Thank you for your help